# Valid routes iBGP advertisements

Tags: routing, bgp

Routers announce to their iBGP peers, the Best routes for each networks it has in its database

Is it possible, to announce additionally to the Best route, also all the Valid routes to the iBGP peers ?

Comment: An iBGP router cannot announce iBGP-learned prefixes to iBGP peers. That is why iBGP requires a full mesh or a mitigation (route reflectors or confederations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. There is a feature called `additional-paths advertise|install` which is an enhancement to the BGP protocol, but it must be supported by both parties. Also check the BGP PIC feature.

Check [This](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/configuration/15-mt/irg-15-mt-book/bgp_additional_paths.pdf) paper for further reference

Comment: The router can advertise up to 3 additional paths, not *all valid routes*

Answer (score 2):

A Cisco router can install multiple paths into the RIB using the `maximum-paths` command.  This will allow the router to 'load share' among the paths.

However, the router will only advertise the best path to its peers, regardless of how many paths are in the RIB.

Comment: Not entirely accurate statement. Maximum-paths is the amount of paths that can be taken into RIB/FIB for a given prefix, but this is different. Many vendors have support for additional-paths nowadays, which can achieve what is asked in the question.

Comment: Yes, I was just reviewing that as you wrote this.  Thanks for the tip.